# Does Eloquent ORM change CamelCase to underscores?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im getting an error in Laravel using Eloquent which is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'task_manager.rel_developers_projects' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into 
`rel_developers_projects` (`project_id`, `developer_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '1', 2 => '2013-07-31 08:23:35', 3 
=> '2013-07-31 08:23:35', ))
```

However, the Model is called RelDevelopersProject and the table is called RelDevelopersProjects.

Does Eloquent try to convert CamelCased names to underscores?

Comment: don't use camel case table names. Use rel_developers_projects instead. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use camel case for table names.

If you however need to, try this:

```
class RelDevelopersProject extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'RelDevelopersProjects';

}
```

See [eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage) in the Laravel Docs.

Comment: Cheers, I thought it did and knew you could override it, but couldn't find in the docs where it said table names should be camelcased

Comment: Alright. I made a local copy from the Laravel Docs with an auto-update every two weeks. So I'm up-to-date with the docs :-)

Comment: You should update more often, Laravel is updating a lot :) (fortunately!) :)

Comment: @Andreyco Lol true. Just throttling a bit to not spend too much power into the updates :P

Comment: @MarkusHofmann Why should I prefer `snake case` over `camel case`? Any explanation?

Comment: @cept0 As database architectures differ from settings, they can be case-sensitive and case-insensitive. Also some OS are different in how they handle the db filesystem. So to make the database table names more compatible for any future stack changes, it's better to use underscore table names like table_name instead of TableName or tableName or TABLENAME. Another reason are human errors. So if you use CamelCase you might end up with bugs through typos. However, it's all personal preference in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.
Just define the table name as a property in Model

```
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'RelDevelopersProject';
```